# How do I use Python for-loops to get my program to return the right values?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm just practicing/testing for-loops and wondering why this code won't return the right values.

```
a = 'abcdefghijklm'
b = 'nopqrstuvwxyz'
word = input('Give a word\n')
score = 0

for letter in word:
    if letter in a:
        score += score + 1
    else:
        score += score + 2
print(score)
```

Comment: And "The right value" is...? Are we left to divine your intentions?

Comment: What is the purpose of `b` ?

Comment: A "program" does not "return values". A function "returns" values, but you don't have any functions. A "program" may "print" values, or show them in a window, or save them to some place... And it is not clear what you mean by the "right values". What exactly do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

To increment `score` by `1`, you should either `score += 1` or `score = score + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of the += operator you are using.

You should either use 
`score+= 1` and `score+=2`
or `score= score+1` and `score= score+2`

Answer (score 0):

- You're using `score += score + 1`, and that's not right
- You should either use `score += 1` or `score = score + 1`

Answer (score 0):

What output do you exactly expect?
On my first look I'm gonna say maybe you should use `score += 1` instead of `score += score + 1` if you want to increment score by 1.